# Why grain boundary is reactive to acid?

Tags: acid-base, energy

I have read about grain boundary etching. They use acid to make grain boundary visible for light microscope. I know that grain boundary is reactive to acid, but why? Thanks.

Comment: A grain boundary is an area with some amount of disorder, strain, and unterminated bonds. This gives some acids the opening they need. See also dislocation highlighting etches.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the disordered atomic arrangement at the grain boundary which implies higher  internal energy of the constituting atoms and consequently more reactivity (attack by acid, corrosion,...).